# How to calc root and pole from a SYS object

Tags: matlab

I want to calc root and pole from a TF object. But I didn't find a function for that in the manuals.

For example:

I have a given `TF` object. And I want to know where are the roots and the poles.

The purpose is that I have two objects, multiply them and from the result I want to know the roots and poles.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Thanks, but you made a mistake, that are two different questions

Comment: in essence, there is too little difference between these questions IMHO. Also, although I must be starting to get on your nerves now, I'm downvoting it, because you clearly haven't done much [research on the matter](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Why? I tried to find anything in the help function of matlab and via web search engine and so on. (Please don't get me wrong I don't want that you undo it, but help me to improve my research methods)

Comment: I just copied your exact question into Google, included the term "Matlab" and got [this](http://regpro.mechatronik.uni-linz.ac.at/downloads/autpr/Tutorials/MatlabSimulink/Defining%20Transfer%20Functions%20in%20Matlab.htm) as the second result or so...You might also want to try [DuckDuckGo](http://duckduckgo.com/) every now and then, because Google shapes your results based on previous searches, which can sometimes lead to a "Google bubble-lock-in" :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Thanks for the clue with DuckDuckGo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to get the Zero Pole Gain (ZPK) data from the `tf` object. You can do this as follows:

```
G = tf([1], [1 0.1 1]);
[z,p,k] = zpkdata(G);

z % are the zeros (roots as you call them)
p % are the poles
k % is a static gain
```

You can also get a graphical representation using `pzmap(G)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with the control system toolbox, but I'll give it a try.

Reading [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/control/ref/tf.html), and [some background material](http://regpro.mechatronik.uni-linz.ac.at/downloads/autpr/Tutorials/MatlabSimulink/Defining%20Transfer%20Functions%20in%20Matlab.htm), it seems to me like you define TF objects through

```
TF_obj = tf(num, den, ...)
```

where `num` and `den` are vectors of coefficients that define the polynomials in the numerator and denominator, respectively.

**EDIT (2):** If you have an existing TF object `TF_obj`, you can still access the `num` and `den` like so:

```
num = TF_obj.num;
den = TF_obj.den;
```

Now, the *poles* are the roots of the denominator polynomial, whereas the *roots* are the roots of the numerator polynomial. Therefore, using Matlab's [`roots` function](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/roots.html):

```
TF_roots = roots(num);
TF_poles = roots(den);
```

or

```
TF_roots = roots(TF_obj.num);
TF_poles = roots(TF_obj.den);
```

If you want, you can define a little helper function somewhere no Matlab's search path, that allows you to do this in a one-liner:

```
function [rts, pls] = TfRootsPoles(num, den)
    rts = roots(num);
    pls = roots(den);
end
```

so that

```
[TF_roots, TF_poles] = TfRootsPoles(num, den);
```

will be the more readable intuitive version of the above.

You can also use `[z,p,k] = zpkdata(G)` as suggested by Egon, which is essentially the same function, but taking a TF object as its input.

**EDIT (1):** just saw your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889919/roots-doesnt-work-in-a-function). I do consider this a duplicate, since you got that one answered (in exactly the same way as I suggested), so I will cast a close vote on this one.

Comment: Thanks Rody, sry my post was a bit too unprecise. I edit it a bit. You described how to create tf object with given roots and poles. But I need the other way around.

Comment: @PeterLustig: See my edit; you can still use the `num` and `den` in an existing object. I still think there is too little difference with your other question, so the close vote remains.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: do note that the `den` and `num` field of `tf` are cell arrays, so you should use `G.den{1}` etc. to get the polynomials (at least for SISO cases). The recommended way, however, is to use the `tfdata` function (possibly together with the `'v'` option to unpack the 1x1 cell arrays into vectors).

Comment: @Egon: True. I do expect these functions to be not much more than some error-checking and `cellfun` versions of the function above (I can't verify this right now though..)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: there is a bit more going on, as far as I see the implementation is shared within `DynamicSystem`. But for a `tf`, in principle it means calling `roots` on its polynomials. In practice, it might be implemented more numerically sound using some frequency rescaling behind the scenes.

Comment: @Egon: `roots` is pretty accurate and fast, as it uses an eigenvalue method. But dividing by `k` prior to `roots` might be a good idea.